# How to fix Ora-01427 single-row subquery returns more than one row in Update statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

Here is my query:

```
UPDATE CIELA_STATUS 
SET CIELA_STATUS.OSIGURENI = (
  SELECT STG5.OSIGURENI
  FROM CIELA_STATUS_STG5 STG5
  WHERE CIELA_STATUS.UIC = STG5.UIC)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT STG5.OSIGURENI
  FROM CIELA_STATUS_STG5 STG5
  WHERE CIELA_STATUS.UIC = STG5.UIC
  AND nvL(CIELA_STATUS.OSIGURENI, 9999) <> STG5.OSIGURENI)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is this part of your query:

```
SELECT STG5.OSIGURENI
FROM CIELA_STATUS_STG5 STG5
WHERE CIELA_STATUS.UIC = STG5.UIC
```

Is returning multiple rows. You need a way to pick exactly one row from the many for the insert.

If it gives an acceptable result, the easiest way is to use `MIN()` or `MAX()`:

```
SELECT MAX(STG5.OSIGURENI)
FROM CIELA_STATUS_STG5 STG5
WHERE CIELA_STATUS.UIC = STG5.UIC
```

So your whole query would then be:

```
UPDATE CIELA_STATUS 
SET CIELA_STATUS.OSIGURENI = (
  SELECT MAX(STG5.OSIGURENI)
  FROM CIELA_STATUS_STG5 STG5
  WHERE CIELA_STATUS.UIC = STG5.UIC)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT STG5.OSIGURENI
  FROM CIELA_STATUS_STG5 STG5
  WHERE CIELA_STATUS.UIC = STG5.UIC
  AND nvL(CIELA_STATUS.OSIGURENI, 9999) <> STG5.OSIGURENI)
```

If `MAX()` doesn’t give the proper result, you’ll have to engineer a query that selects the appropriate row from the many that match.

Answer (score 1):

As the error says the subquery used to `set` the updated column produced more than one row.

The most probably explanation is that the `UIC` column is **not** a primary/unique key in the table `CIELA_STATUS_STG5`

Quick check

```
select UIC, count(*)
from CIELA_STATUS_STG5
group by UIC
having count(*) > 1
```

You'll see the duplicated keys and you must decide how to recover. E.g. delete duplicates, or use only `MAX` value in the update or use the newes/oldest rows etc.

Note - to more focused selection of the duplicates, as you do not use the whole table `CIELA_STATUS_STG5` in the update use this query, which makes the same *restriction* as used in the update:

```
SELECT 
  STG5.UIC, count(*) cnt
FROM CIELA_STATUS_STG5 STG5
WHERE  STG5.UIC IN (
SELECT  CIELA_STATUS.UIC
FROM CIELA_STATUS 
WHERE EXISTS
      (SELECT STG5.OSIGURENI
                         FROM CIELA_STATUS_STG5 STG5
                         WHERE  CIELA_STATUS.UIC = STG5.UIC
                         AND nvL(CIELA_STATUS.OSIGURENI,9999) <> STG5.OSIGURENI)
)
GROUP BY STG5.UIC
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```